# Is the sequence $0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,\ldots$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The sequence $0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,\ldots$ is divergent according to a video I watched on WebAssign but the comment was very informal. Could someone provide a hint about the formal proof that the sequence is divergent?

Comment: Formal proof needs a formal definition of the sequence. Currently it may be convergent

Comment: What is the formal definition of a sequence?

Comment: If a sequence is convergent to $a$, then all its subsequences converge to $a$.

Comment: @egreg How can one use the fact you wrote?

Comment: If it were convergent, what would be its limit?

Comment: I do not know what a subsequence is.

Comment: @Bob This is to stress Coolwater's point: using your somewhat inadequate notations, you would probably declare that the sequence 0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,… is convergent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the series converges to some limit $L$, then all but finitely many of its terms are within a distance of $0.1$ from $L$, i.e. between $L-0.1$ and $L+0.1$.  But $0$ and $1$ cannot both be between $L-0.1$ and $L+0.1$.  The triangle inequality shows that.

Comment: perfect answer.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, $t=0,100100010000\ldots$ is irrational, and your sequence is s.t. $x_n$ gives the $n$-th digit of $t$ and thus can't converge. But anyway, it's not the exercise to show that it's irrational. First, it's clear that $0\leq x_n\leq 1$ and that $x_{n_k}\in \{x_1,x_4,x_8,x_{13},\ldots\}$ is a subsequence that is s.t. $x_{n_k}=1$ for all $k$. And $x_{m_k}\in\{x_0,x_2,x_5,x_9,x_{14},\ldots\}$ is a subsequence s.t. $x_{m_k}=0$ for all $k$. Therefore $$\limsup_{n\to\infty }x_n=1$$
and $$\liminf_{n\to\infty }x_n=0$$
and thus, the sequence doesn't converge.

Comment: It would be unfortunate if the person posting the question were to think that this is a good way to think about such a question.

Comment: Why it wouldn't be ? @MichaelHardy

Comment: First things first. There's a really simple argument straight from the definition of convergence of a sequence, showing that this sequence does not converge.  A person who doesn't know how to find that simple argument has a deficient understanding of the definition, and an answer should expalin what they've missed. Instead, you're going into stuff involving irrational numbers that is not applicable to sequences in general and is far from straightforward.

Answer (score 4):

Every convergent sequence must be Cauchy, right?

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that $\lim_n x_n=L$, this means that
$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N\in \mathbb{N}\ : \ n\geqslant N \Rightarrow |x_n-L|<\epsilon$$
Let's fix a random $N_0\in \mathbb{N}$. We notice that if $n\geqslant N_0$ then $|x_n-L|<\epsilon$ can't hold for any $\epsilon <\frac12$. Therefore the sequence doesn't converge.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that the $n$-th term of the given sequence $(x_n)$ is 1 if $n+1$ is a triangular number, and is 0 otherwise.

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is convergent, then $\exists a \in \Bbb R$ such that $x_n \to a$.

i.e. $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\forall n \ge N, |x_n - a| < \epsilon$.

Case 1: $a = 0$

Take $\epsilon_0 = \dfrac12$.  Then it's easy to see that if $n+1$ is a triangular number and $n \ge N$, then $|x_n - a| = 1 - 0 > \dfrac12 = \epsilon_0$.

Case 2: $a = 1$

Take $\epsilon_0 = \dfrac12$.  Then it's easy to see that if $n+1$ is not a triangular number and $n \ge N$, then $|x_n - a| = |0 - 1| > \dfrac12 = \epsilon_0$.

Case 3: $a \ne 0$ and $a \ne 1$

Take $\epsilon_0 = \min\{|a|,|a - 1|\} > 0$.  Then $|x_n - a| = |1 - a|$ or $|a - 0| \ge \epsilon_0$.

In either case, the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of the convergence of sequence is contradicted since we can find an $\epsilon_0$ which doesn't fit into the definition.